Swift: How do I align my image and the textbox below?
I am trying to align an image with a textbox in a Swift application.
How do I get this to look correct?
This is the version of code I have that is funky. I've tried a lot of things and I need help, please.
ForEach(listing.items, id: \.self) { i in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                    Image(i.itemImageUrl)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .overlay(
                            ZStack {
                                Text("$ \(i.priceOfItem)")
                                    .font(.body)
                                    .padding(5)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .opacity(0.7)
                                .cornerRadius(12)
                                .padding(10),
                            alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                   
                        Text("Description: \(i.itemDescription)")
                        .frame(width: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading).padding(8)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                            .font(.body)
                }
                .padding()


I am aiming for the alignment on the left, but when the code renders within another view there's a weird white space.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code. Show the code of your other container view since this where you say the problem is.

If you want the images to fill the full width then you could use ViewThatFits to choose between scaled-to-fill and scaled-to-fit:

when an image has an aspect ratio that is taller than the screen, it is scaled to fill
otherwise, when an image has an aspect ratio that is wider than the screen, it is scaled to fit.

ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
    let itemImage = Image(i.itemImageUrl)
    itemImage
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
    itemImage
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
}

You might also want to wrap the ForEach with a ScrollView.
Your example code is using a deprecated version of the .overlay modifier. The modifiers .foregroundColor and .cornerRadius are also deprecated, use .foregroundStyle and .clipShape instead. And... you don't need to nest the Text inside a ZStack. So I would suggest changing the overlay to the following:
.overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
    Text("$ \(i.priceOfItem)")
        .font(.body)
        .padding(5)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .background(Color.black)
        .opacity(0.7)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
        .padding(10)
}

That just leaves the labels below the images. You might have noticed, your existing code was giving errors in the console:

Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite).

This is because, .infinity is not valid as a width. However, it is valid as maxWidth, this is the only change needed here:
Here is the fully-updated example:
ScrollView {
    ForEach(listing.items, id: \.self) { i in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
            ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
                let itemImage = Image(i.itemImageUrl)
                itemImage
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                itemImage
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                Text("$ \(i.priceOfItem)")
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding(5)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .opacity(0.7)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                    .padding(10)
            }
            Text("Description: \(i.itemDescription)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                .padding(8)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .font(.body)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}



Did you checked if maybe the image itself has a white space?
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
        Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                Text(1300.75, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding(5)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .opacity(0.7)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .padding([.trailing, .bottom], 20)
            }
            .border(Color.black, width: 1) // This border shows if the image is actually as big as you want it to be
        Text("Description: A large black folder")
            .frame(alignment: .topLeading).padding(8)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .font(.body)
    }
    .padding()

